# create option page using jetengine to change product listing grid

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, jet-engine

I have multiple listing grid in my home page that shows my woocommerce products , I want to create an option page in my wordpress website that my admin can go there and choose which listing grid show products of which category , Im using jetEngine and elementor
How Can I achive that ?

I tried jetEngine query builder but the problem is there is not a dynamic value option both for option page select field value and listing grid Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your option page setting , and create fields settings with the categories you want , just remember to put categories ID number as value of options,
then go to the query builder and create query for each listing ,

```
query type -> post
tax query -> Taxonomy -> product_cat
Field -> term ID
Terms -> Option value -> choose from the option you created
```

Hope it helps...